# Web Deploy missing msvcr90.dll

Tags: visual-studio, umbraco, webdeploy

Visual Studio 2012 using Web Deploy to create a Web Deployment Package.
The publish worked before, now it just started failing with an error unable to find msvcr90.dll.  I've tried restarting and removing unnecessary references.  It is an Umbraco 6 site.

```
Error 102   
Copying file bin\amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcr90.dll to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcr90.dll failed. Could not find file 'bin\amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcr90.dll'.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets    2554
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a little on how you have the site set up in Visual Studio, but it sounds like the `/bin/` folder and `/bin/amd64/` subfolder are 'included' in the project but at the latter (or it's contents) is missing from the file system.

Comment: This is correct.  I usually ignore any files in a bin folder in my .gitignore.  For some reason the Umbraco nuget package adds add references items in the bin folder.  I removed them from the project and all is well.  Something to do with SQLCE.